# How do I add a blank line after the scanner object?

Tags: java, syntax, java-8

I am very new to Java and I am having some issues making my code do what I want it to.
So this is my code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
int another_int_value = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

This outputs the message `Please enter an integer:` and then a blank line where the user can type an integer let's say the user inputs the integer `3`.
The following line starts right after the `3`, but I want it to skip one, how do I make this happen?
I tried adding the line `input.nextLine()` but then the user has to press ENTER, twice and I don't want that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could have it to where the user inputs code after the semicolon by removing the .println and just using .print. No extra code needed after.

```
System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
int another_int_value = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        System.out.println();
        int another_int_value = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```